# add and remove css for z-index dynamically

Tags: jquery, css, dynamic

`$('.sn').css({'z-index':'-1000'});`
 (hide whole group) on load whole class, and from that class i want to show or appy css    `$('#item1').css({'z-index':'1000'});`(show only one from the group) on click of some element dynamicaly but this do not happen pls help me?
and when i use hide() & show() methods it works fine.

```
//on click ..
$(document).on('click','#slider1prev',function(){   

    selected = selected-1;



    if(my_text != ""){
        $('#noteImage'+selected).css({'z-index':'1000'});
        $('#noteText'+selected).css({'z-index':'1000'});
    }

});
```

//onload..

```
$('.sn').css({'z-index':'-1000'});
$('.notes').css({'z-index':'-1000'});
```

Comment: could you please reformat your question?

Comment: you really need to look on ur code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you just use `show()` and `hide()` methods instead? Z-index just changes the stack-order of the elements and only work on `positioned elements`. So if you want to use z-index. set the elements `position` property either to `absolute` or to `fixed`.

Read More about [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp).

so instead of doing

```
.css({'z-index':'1000'});
```

do

```
.css({'position': 'absolute', 'z-index':'1000'});
```

or

```
.css({'position': 'fixed', 'z-index':'1000'});
```